# Register COM component (interop.Acrobat.dll)

Tags: com

I have seen similar question but none seem to help me. I am a beginner so please make it very simple for me.
I am trying to convert a pdf file to image file by using Acrobat.dll
My problem is I don't know how to register the COM component because:

1. Underproperties-->Build-->Register for COM Interop is disabled (I am using C# express)
2. Using regsvr32 + path + file name is not working for me

I want to know why Interop is disabled
Also under properties-->Application-->Assembly Information-->make assembly COM visible: is already enabled

Comment: To register COM component, you must have administrator privileges. You have to make sure that you run regsvr32 with admin rights.

Comment: The interop library should **not** be registered.  It just contains declarations for the COM component in a format that the CLR understands.  If you need help with installing an Adobe product properly so that your program could also work on another machine then contact Adobe for support.  Whomever uses it will need to purchase a license from Adobe, Acrobat is not a free product.

Comment: I see, I thought it was free since I already installed the free acrobat and has the Interop.Acrobat.dll file.
Thanks for the info